# google sheets additional custom column in filter

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, sequence, google-query-language

I like to add an additional column in filter formula. This one is working, but not exactly what i need:

```
=FILTER({detroit!A2:N,"detroit"&row(detroit!A2:A)},detroit!A2:A<>"")
```

I need only the text "detroit" without the row number, something like this:

```
=FILTER({detroit!A2:N,"detroit"},detroit!A2:A<>"")
```

I think i need to use a function for every cell, like row, what gives back nothing?

It also have to be fast to calculate, because of the size of the data.

[image: the_issue]

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this where Z column is empty:

```
=FILTER({detroit!A2:N, detroit!Z2:Z&"detroit"}, detroit!A2:A<>"")
```

if you dont have any empty column use:

```
=FILTER({detroit!A2:N, 
 IFERROR(SEQUENCE(ROWS(detroit!A2:A))/0)&"detroit"}, detroit!A2:A<>"")
```

also you could do:

```
=QUERY(detroit!A2:N, 
 "select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,'detroit' 
  where A is not null 
  label 'detroit'''", 0)
```

Comment: A really huuuuuge thanks :) All solutions are handy, depending on the sheet structure.
Special thanks for the Query solution. 
You are awesome.